# chrome keeps sending me to iGoogle webpage, how can I stop it?

Tags: google-chrome

On one computer, every time I go to

http://www.google.com/

I get redirected to

http://www.google.com/ig?hl=en

My homepage is set to
http://www.google.com/
I'd like it to go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just choose "Classic Home" in the settings for google.com? (Found on the top right of google.com both versions). Maybe I'm misinterpreting your problem.

[image]

Comment: ah I see, thanks for the screenshot. I guess maybe I didn't realise the username and the gear bring down different menus, and the down arrow that appears when logged in, is part of the username one. I had to click the gear itself.  That screenshot helped.. it gets a bit sickening with all tese new menus and rubbish..

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "wrench" icon
Choose settings
In the startup section click on
the pages to open section and delete the google.com/ig entry
replace it with plain google.com

Chrome treats startup pages and home pages as different things. No idea why they thought this was a good idea.